# Can I resize an EXT4 image for QEMU?

Tags: ext4, resize, qemu

Is there a way to resize a built image used in QEMU?

I have built an image, the output format is ext4. As I am running some test and need additional libraries and just want to transfer them via SCP, I need more space, than provided 64MB.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way, just use:

```
resize2fs <image_name> <size><K/M/G>
```